# Can't center div and CSS Validation

Tags: css

I'm trying to center the entire pricing table but I cannot seem to do so. I am using class ePricingTable as my container. Also, can someone check my css and let me know if it's being done correctly?

```
<div class="ePricingTable">
<div class="ePricingBox left">
    <div class="ePackageName left">
        <h1>Personal</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ePackageInfoLogo">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <ul class="triangle green">
            <li><strong>4 </strong>Design Concepts</li>
            <li><strong>2 </strong>Dedicated Designers</li>
            <li><strong>2 </strong>Design Revisions</li>
            <li><strong>7 </strong>Final Files</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ePriceBox ePriceShadow">
        <h2>$179</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ePricingButton"><a class="readon smallmarginright" href="index.php?option=com_proforms&amp;view=form&amp;jid=2&amp;Itemid=188"><span>WORK REQUEST</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ePricingBox eBestValue">
    <div class="ePackageName">
        <h1>Business</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ePackageInfoLogoBestValue">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <ul class="triangle green">
            <li><strong>6 </strong>Design Concepts</li>
            <li><strong>3 </strong>Dedicated Designers</li>
            <li><strong>Unlimited </strong>Design Revisions</li>
            <li><strong>7 </strong>Final Files</li>
            <li><strong>250 </strong>Printed Business Cards</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ePriceBox eValuePriceShadow">
        <h2>$299</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ePricingButton"><a class="readon smallmarginright" href="index.php?option=com_proforms&amp;view=form&amp;jid=2&amp;Itemid=188"><span>WORK REQUEST</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="h015">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="ePricingBox right">
    <div class="ePackageName right">
        <h1 epricingplain="">Business Pro</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ePackageInfoLogo">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <ul class="triangle green">
            <li><strong>10 </strong>Design Concepts</li>
            <li><strong>5 </strong>Dedicated Designers</li>
            <li><strong>Unlimited </strong>Design Revisions</li>
            <li><strong>7 </strong>Final Files</li>
            <li><strong>1000 </strong>Printed Business Cards</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ePriceBox ePriceShadow">
        <h2>$499</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ePricingButton"><a class="readon smallmarginright" href="index.php?option=com_proforms&amp;view=form&amp;jid=2&amp;Itemid=188"><span>WORK REQUEST</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.ePricingTable {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}

.ePricingBox {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F6F7;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #D2D3D4;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
             box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);;
    margin: 0;
}

.eBestValue {   
    margin: -15px 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
         -moz-border-radius: 6px;
              border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
             box-shadow: 2px 2px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);;

}

.ePackageName {
    background: #505152; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #505152 0%, #28292a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#505152), color-stop(100%,#28292a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #505152 0%,#28292a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #505152 0%,#28292a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #505152 0%,#28292a 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #505152 0%,#28292a 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#505152', endColorstr='#28292a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000000;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0;
    height: 50px;
}

.ePackageInfoWeb {
    height: 395px;
}

.ePackageInfoWebBestValue {
    height: 410px;
}

.ePricingButton {
    height: 60px;
}

.ePriceBox {
    height: 60px;
}

.ePackageInfoLogo {
    height: 210px;
}
.ePackageInfoLogoBestValue {
    height: 225px;
}

.left {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.right {
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.ePackageName h1 {
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:28px;
}

.ePricingTable ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.ePriceShadow
{
text-shadow: 0 0 2px #4F5051;
}

.eValuePriceShadow
{
text-shadow: 0 0 2px #2B9DE6;
}
```

Comment: You are also missing your closing `</div>`.  On a side note you will get more upvotes for clear and understandable Questions.  Consider editing it so that others can more easily identify with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
.ePricingTable {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but then you have to create an extra outer div with the specific width.
`IE` needs `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` otherwise `margin: 0 auto;` won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.ePricingTable {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

to

```
.ePricingTable {
    width: 490px;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/35M7H/)

Answer (score 0):

1 - the parent element (ePricingTable), is missing a closing tag at the bottom of your HTML.

2 - Your CSS seems to be fine.

3 - If you add the missing closing tag, the container will be centered. but since your children elements total width is less than 1000px (which you've set for the container element), content won't perfectly centered to the center of the page.

Solutions to get them centered perfectly:

1 - set each ePricingBox an absolute width in pixels then calculate the ePricingTable's width and set that in pixels as well.

```
.ePricingBox{
    width:300px;
}

.ePricingTable{
    width:900px; /* THREE ePricingBox s */
 }
```

or give the container element an absolute width and define the children width using percents.

```
.ePricingBox{
    width:30%; /* ONE-THIRD OF THE PARENT ELEMENT'S WIDTH */
}

.ePricingTable{
    width:900px;
}
```

2 - if you don't know the exact width of each ePricingBox, you can also use CSS's table displays.

```
.ePricingTable{
    display:table;
 }

.ePricingBox{
    display:table-cell;
 }
```

this should to the trick.